# Como puedo agregar archivos como un recurso en una aplicación de escritorio en c#?

Tags: c#, .net, aplicación-escritorio

Estoy tratando de crear una aplicación de escritorio con c#, y lo que deseo es poder agregar unos archivos para que cuando se instale la aplicación, se agreguen los archivos a una carpeta dentro de la instalación. La extensión de los archivos que quiero agregar son .key y .cer.

Alguien sabe como hacerlo?

Comment: Puedes usar `InstallShield`. Antes de intentar, investiga un poco mas y te recomiendo [edit] tu pregunta con mas detalles. Por favor lee: [cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, exactamente que es lo que no es claro ?, leí lo que mencionas y no veo la falla, ¿es acaso el signo de interrogación inicial ?. Pregunto para que no me pase en futuras ocasiones.

Gracias y saludos...

Comment: Rafael, debes proveer mas información. Por ejemplo, tu dices: `cuando se instale la aplicación, se agreguen los archivos a una carpeta` ¿exactamente cómo estás haciendo la instalación?

Answer (score 2):

Puedes agregarlos en tu archivo de recursos o al crear tu instalador puedes incluir los archivos en una carpeta, que la momento de instalar la aplicación serán copiados dichos archivos en la ruta de tu aplicación.

Saludos.